# Two membership tables: aspnet_Membership and webpages_Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am working on my first ASP.Net MVC 4 app.  I selected the Internet Application option and started with a LocaDB instance that had 4 tables in it (webpages_*).

I'm adding logging and error handling and I want to add ASP.Net Health Monitoring. To do that I had to run aspnet_regsql and now I have all of the aspnet_* tables along with the webpages_*.

What tables do I actually need for the Health Monitoring?  Do I need all of them?  Can I get rid of aspnet_Membership, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had tables for both Membership Provider and SimpleMembership Provider.  Choosing one provider over the other allowed me to delete the cooresponding tables.